# why `splice.apply(arguments, 0)` fails while `splice.call(arguments, 0)` returns Array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to turn `arguments` variable which is accessible inside function into an array. I've tried two ways:

```
Array.prototype.splice.apply(arguments, 0) //fails
Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0) //return array
```

Can you please guys elaborate on why the first option fails while the second one succeeds?

Comment: The second argument to `.apply()` should be an array, like `[0]`.

Comment: That is, in fact, the main difference between `call` and `apply`.

Comment: Indeed, so `Array.prototype.splice.apply(arguments, [0])` should work. `apply()` and `call()` are not the same!

Comment: The error message `Function.prototype.apply: argumentsArray is not an array-like object` (or something along the lines of this) should be clear enough, or at least tell you to [check the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Because http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3

Comment: @Pointy, thanks, can you make your comment an answer so that I mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because <strike>`Array.prototype.splice.apply(arguments, 0)` is (roughly) equivalent to `arguments.splice([0])`</strike>, as it has been said by others before me, `apply` expects an Array as its second argument. If you wanted to retrieve the n-first parameters, you could do `Array.prototype.splice.apply(arguments, [0,n])` which would be (roughly) equivalent to `arguments.splice.(0,n)`.

On the contrary, `call` works with any type of parameters. `Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0)` is (roughly) equivalent to `arguments.splice(0)`, and since `splice` expects an integer as its first argument and not an array, the second solution works (but not the first one). Thus, `Array.prototype.splice.apply(arguments, [0])` would also work as Jeroen Noten suggested it.

Please note that the "equivalences" I'm referring to would **not** actually work since `arguments` is **not** an Array but rather an Array-like object.

However, the technique you mentioned is frequently used to turn an Array-like object into a proper Array.

**EDIT** : I edited my answer as it contained a big mistake. Thanks to cookiemonster for the correction.

Comment: Did you read what I wrote ? oO

Comment: Yes I did. The lack of equivalence has nothing to do with `arguments` being Array-like.

Comment: Like cookiemonster said, it's not the `splice` that fails.

Comment: Oohhh my bad, you're absolutely right @cookiemonster. Apologies.
I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure ? I just tried on JSFiddle and got "TypeError: arguments.splice is not a function".

Comment: Ah, I missed what you meant. I thought you were referring to the former (`.call`, `.apply`) as the equivalent. For a direct call, the method would need to be placed directly on the `arguments` object.

Comment: Ahh. No, I just meant that *since* `arguments` is an Array-like object, we *have to* use the `Array.prototype.call|apply(arguments,...)` syntax to turn it into a proper array. But you're right, this technique is only possible *because* `arguments` *is* an Array-like object. Quiproquo :p

I hope all is clear now :)